# connection.select_all vs select with joins in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, join

Here below, lo belongs to titres, titre has many lo.

When I use:

```
    LO.select(["los.id","date_ord","soc","pv"]).joins(:titre).
        where(['year(date_ord) = ? and pv is not null',"#{date_ord}"]).
        group("num_ordre").order("soc,date_ord")
```

it does not retrieve the field soc from titre.

Whereas if I use:

```
search_year = "year(date_ord) = '#{date_ord}'"
connection.select_all("select los.id, date_ord, soc, pv " + 
    "from los inner join titres on los.titre_id=titres.id " + 
    "where #{search_year} and pv is not null " + 
    "group by num_ordre order by soc, date_ord;")
```

it does retrieve it.

Is there something fondamental I'm missing here?

Or does select limits the retrieving of fields tho those of the from the from database table, and nothing from the join table?

Is there a nicier way to do this query so that it gives the same result as the connection.select_all version?

Environment: rails 3.0.5 with jruby 1.6 (ruby 1.8.7).

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Active Record finder methods are attached with the Model calling them. Therefore, they will expect result follow the model format and build an object of this model.

Meanwhile, connection.select_all doesn't depend on any model and simply return an array of hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your created query to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all` to avoid having the model created and still have the results returned as if you had passed it a raw sql string:

```
query = LO.select(["los.id","date_ord","soc","pv"]).joins(:titre).
        where(['year(date_ord) = ? and pv is not null',"#{date_ord}"]).
        group("num_ordre").order("soc,date_ord")

data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query)
```